# Creating conditional metric using JSON INPUT in Kibana

Tags: json, kibana

Using Kibana 6.2.1

I want to output '0' if the metric value is <0 else 'metric value' for a column in Data Table.

I tried the following JSON input:

```
{"script":
  "if(doc['<<fieldname>>'].value <0) then {0} else {doc['<<fieldname>>'].value}"
}
```

This script is erroneous.
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
{
  "script": "if (doc['fieldname'].value < 0) {return 0} else {return doc['fieldname'].value}"
}
```

Comment: even shorter: `{ "script": "doc['fieldname'].value < 0 ? 0 : doc['fieldname'].value" }`